# Edit button, Page Not found

Tags: 2013, error, edit, page-not-found

My sharepoint was recently migrated to a new server.  Changed the url for all the pages.  I have an important page that contains lists grouped by categories.  I would frequently use the Edit button to move an item from one category.  Since the migration, when I click the edit button it takes me to 'Page not found' as opposed to opening window that allows me to edit the item.  I'm aware that I can create views but would love to keep the page as is but can't figure out how to make the edit button work.

I also have a 'Create New Item' button on the page which allows me to create a new item but even the newly created items go to "Page Not Found" after clicking the Edit button.

Comment: seems your specific view is not present here, or the ViewGUID has changed.. 1st verify if the view is present... I hope it is list view your edit button targets to

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a custom webpart, you have to open the custom webpart source code to check the URLS, try to open the aspx file in the Sharepoint Designer or open the solution with Visual Studio depending where the webpart was developed. I had the same issue when migrating sharepoint 2010 to 2013, all custom webparts was updated.